# Conditional function return nothing, correct syntax ? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Instead to write a big "if" statement, I want to know if this syntax is ok ?
I just use the word return if the condition is not respected.

```
@IBAction func SignUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if passwordField1.text != passwordField2.text {
        // password dont match
        // Pop error
        return
    }

    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = emailField.text
    user.password = passwordField1.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (suceeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Log the user
        }else{
            // Display an error
        }
    }
}
```

Or I need to write it like this :

```
@IBAction func SignUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if passwordField1.text == passwordField2.text {

        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = emailField.text
        user.password = passwordField1.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (suceeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Log the user
            }else{
                // Display an error
            }
        }
    }else{
        // Error : password dont match
       // Pop error
    }
}
```

the first syntax is more clear if need to try many conditions but I'm not sure it's good to write the code like that. Thanks

**SOLUTION :** (with matt answer and Apple Doc on "guard" :
The first statement need to be write like this :

```
guard passwordField1.text == passwordField2.text else {
        print("pop error")
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I'd use the first syntax, expressed as a `guard` statement:

```
guard passwordField1.text == passwordField2.text else { return }
```

This is exactly what `guard` is for: if conditions are not met, go no further. A succession of multiple `guard` statements (because multiple conditions must be met) is quite standard.